Why NLA strip on Hold donst work?
I have a strip action on Nothing, and then one before that is with hold , but it shows as Hold forwards. This worked previously in 4.0, what happend?
The images, the first , the little one action Hold donst work, in the image below, I had to add a track to had HOLD option enabled , but i dont want this on top, just just next to squarerigaction.002 (Nohting action)


This on later versions worked fine , what happend? I m using 4.2.1
